# Clear a range by clicking a tick box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, typeerror, undefined

I am looking to add a script to clear a range by clicking a tick box. I'm getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15XzVh4WFxDAxzbrCcKHqStE63nTSAeJhuIvSEMk6K_8/edit#gid=1000705976

I added a script found on this website and think I made the necessary adjustments but something is wrong.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your current script and your current Spreadsheet, from your showing error message of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined`, I'm worried that if you want to use the simple trigger of `onEdit` trigger, you might have directly run the function `onEdit(e)` with the script editor. If my understanding is correct, how about checking the checkbox on Spreadsheet? But, if my guess was not correct, I apologize. And, can you show your current script in your question?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's very likely that you are runing a function that requires a parameter. Please checkout the links shown in the box below the question title. If you need further help, please [edit] the question to all all the relevant details direclty into the question body (code from your script, an a brief description of your spreasheet structure, among other relevant details).